# Possible to prompt for input in excel?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to promt a user for an value input in excel and not use VBA or C++ scripts? Or can this only be done using VBA/C++?

I'm very new to all excels features.

Regards

Comment: If you got a value from the user then how would you use it?

Comment: These values would be used in calculations of bending moment/shear forces in beam/bridge analysis. Values would just be linked to equations in tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prompting in that kind of way can only be done with VBA.

However, you can create a data validation rule without VBA that can prompt a user when they enter an incorrect value: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/apply-data-validation-to-cells-HP010072600.aspx

Comment: Thank you. These restrictions will help a lot.